# Rx Retry() not working as expected

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am experimenting with Reactive Extensions to fetch a bunch of RSS items. I based myself on a blog post by Tim Greenfield: [Silverlight Rx DataClient within MVVM](http://programmerpayback.com/2010/03/22/silverlight-rx-dataclient-within-mvvm/).

I'm using it within a desktop application, but the code is similar.

The problem I'm having is in understanding the `Retry()` functions. It doesn't seem to be doing what I expect and on what I'm expecting it.

```
var items = new List<RssItem>();
WebHelper.DownloadXmlFileAsync<RssItem>(new Uri(URI), "item")
    .Retry(2)
    .Finally(PublishResults)
    .Subscribe(items.Add, ProcessError, () => ProcessCompleted(items));
```

When I pass in a valid URI, this works without any issues. When I make a typo in the URI it reports a 404 error through the `ProcessError()` function, as one would expect, but it's only reported once. I would have expected it to show this error twice.

So it seems that the `Retry()` function is not operating on my web request, but it looks like it actually applies on the functions which are passed to `Subscribe()`. I could be wrong here though.

How can I make sure the `Retry()` call applies on the web request?

Extra code:

```
public static class WebHelper
{
    public static HttpWebRequest CreateHttp(Uri uri)
    {
        return CreateHttp(uri, "GET");
    }

    public static HttpWebRequest CreateHttp(Uri uri, string method)
    {
        if (uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttp && uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The specified URI does not use HTTP or HTTPS.", "uri");
        }

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = method;

        return request;
    }

    public static IObservable<T> DownloadXmlFileAsync<T>(Uri uri, string elementName) where T : class
    {
        return (from request in Observable.Return(CreateHttp(uri))
                from response in Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse)()
                let stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                where stream != null
                from item in XmlReader.Create(stream).GetXmlItem<T>(elementName).ToObservable()
                select item);
    }
}

public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetXmlItem<T>(this XmlReader reader, string elementName) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        while (reader.GoToElement(elementName))
        {
            yield return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }
    }

    public static bool GoToElement(this XmlReader reader, string elementName)
    {
        do
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == elementName)
            {
                return true;
            }
        } while (reader.Read());

        return false;
    }
}

XmlRoot("item")]
public class RssItem
{
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("pubDate")]
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Title: {0}", Title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Rx grammar for sequences is defined as:

> OnNext* (OnError | OnCompleted)?

Receiving either an `OnError` or an `OnCompleted` signals the end of the sequence and subscriptions on the pipeline are expected to be torn down.

In the context of the operators:

`observable.Retry(n)` is: Re-subscribe to `observable` when an `OnError` is received, upto n times.

`observable.Finally(action)` is: Execute `action` on receiving `OnError|OnCompleted`

Retry is meant to be used with cold observables ([Lee Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393615/lee-campbell) has [a good post on this](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)) where subscription essentially causes the source to start.

Similarly `Repeat` is exactly like `Retry` except it resubscribes on receiving an `OnCompleted`.

To see this in action, we can create an observable which will "fail" for the first n times, and then succeeds.
Now for some code:

```
    private static IObservable<int> ErrorProducer(int i)
    {
        int count = 0;
        return Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing work");

            if (count++ < i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                observer.OnError(new Exception());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                observer.OnNext(count);
                observer.OnCompleted();                    
            }
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
```

For a producer which fails always:

```
      print(ErrorProducer(3).Retry(2));
```

Gives:

```
Doing work <-- Subscription
Failed
Doing work <-- Resubscription
Failed
OnError(System.Exception)
Finally
```

For a producer which eventually succeeds:

```
print(ErrorProducer(2).Retry(3));

Doing work
Failed
Doing work
Failed
Doing work
Done
OnNext(3) <-- Succeeded
OnCompleted()
Finally
```

If you wanted your process error function to be called as many times as it retries, it should be placed before the `Retry`.

i.e., `seq.Do(value => { }, exception => {  }).Retry(n)`

You can read up on using hot/cold observables, and using the async pattern with Rx to clarify your understanding.

Comment: Your answer provided some good insights and also allowed me to search the internet with some specific keywords resulting in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/rx/thread/96a06e27-9c02-4177-ae6a-04b8a7f966e5 which gave me a bit more insight in the way observables work.

Comment: @JensenSomers Glad I could be of help. Sorry about not being very specific about the exact cause of your problem. Documentation on applying Rx is scarce, and I'm hoping these general answers might be of use to someone who's trying to learn Rx, in the future.

Comment: If everyone will be as exited about Rx as I am, I'm sure proper documentation and larger use-case examples will pop up in the near future. :-)

Comment: @JensenSomers Btw, it might be easier in some cases to use Tasks instead of the Begin/End async pattern. You can use `task.ToObservable()` to get the result of a task as an observable.

Comment: Thanks for the plug Asti, I think the IntroToRx.com content is much better however. http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html

Comment: @LeeCampbell I did not know about this. What a fantastic resource. I wish had something like this when I was learning Rx (basically sat through all channel 9 videos). P.S. I've updated the links. P.P.S https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1928972/rf/youre_awesome.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Asti's answer is spot on. I just wanted to add some additional information in case you wanted to know how to expose multiple Errors for a single logical sequence.

As Asti points out, you can only terminate a sequence once. This termination can be either an error or a completion (OnError|OnCompleted).

However there is nothing stopping you having nested observable sequences! If you did want to see multiple error messages then consider a scenario where you returned an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`. The inner sequence is the data sequence (the sequence you currently have). When this sequence Errors then it can no longer be used, so the Outer sequence could produce an new inner data sequence.

This may seem a bit odd, but it is a supported concept in Rx as operators like Merge and Switch already cater for these nested sequences. This style of Rx is touched in in my book, IntroToRx in the [Nested Sequences](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#NestedObservables) paragraph and then again in more detail in [Sequences of Coincidence](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html) chapter

I hopes this helps you to see other possibilities of how to Rx in the future.